# .Net Core 3.1 application unable to display page like html 'postwindow'

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, razor-pages

First of all please run this code in console "window.open("http://www.google.com",'','postwindow');"
It will open new window as "postwindow".

Well I have project in .Net Core 3.1 using Razor Pages. I want to display every page as postwindow as you can see in attached screenshot, I did lot of search on google but didn't find any helpful solution.

I am thinking if we can add some metadata tag for that or any change in document type etc.

Please guide me.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare headers the 1st request in working and non working situation.  You didn't provide a lot of details of what is the issue.  You may have cookies that is the difference between working and non working conditions.  You may have credential issues.  If you close all browsers you have to establish new credentials.  So sometimes it is best once you get credentials is to open second browser to do display additional pages.

Comment: `postwindow` isn't a valid [window feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features).  Any window with an invalid window feature will open like that.  e.g.:  `window.open("http://www.google.com",'','phasedplasmarifle')`